# Use javascript to allow multiple highlights by users

Tags: javascript, dom, highlight

I am trying to allow students reading a webpage to highlight multiple areas of text.  I have some javascript that sort of works.  On a mouseup event, it adds a span around the selected text, but it throws a DOMException when the selection crosses another tag (e.g., paragraph) because you end up with improperly nested tags. See:

https://jsfiddle.net/pinecone/or6tjasg/

Any suggestions on how I might approach this?  Thanks for your help.

---

```
    document.getElementById('highlight-area').addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
  highlightSelection();
});

function highlightSelection() {

  if (window.getSelection) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
      var extracContents = range.cloneContents();
      if (extracContents.childNodes.length === 1) {
        range.deleteContents();
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = "highlight";
        span.appendChild(extracContents);
        range.insertNode(span);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the "if", it will work just fine:

```
function highlightSelection() {

  if (window.getSelection) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
      var extracContents = range.cloneContents();
      console.dir(extracContents.childNodes)
      // if (extracContents.childNodes.length === 1) {
      range.deleteContents();
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      span.className = "highlight";
      span.appendChild(extracContents);
      range.insertNode(span);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
      // }
    }
  }
}
```

In a intersection you will have 3 childNodes (extracContents.childNodes).
You can also set a color with opacity to see all intersections:

```
.highlight {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .7);
}
```

- Remove !important